# Random() in a user defined arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

im new to java and coding in general so be gentle.

So I have a class called films which just contains getFilmID(), getFilmTitle(), getFilmDuration() etc methods. I don't feel the need to include the code for this class but it is relevant.

I have a second class where I want to display a random film which the user has stored in the arraylist called myfilms.

So far i have

the array list

```
public static ArrayList<Films> myfilms = new ArrayList<Films>();
```

and the random method

```
private static void randomFilm()
{
    int num = (int) (Math.random()*myfilms);
    System.out.println("The film is: " + myfilms);
}
```

"The operator * is undefined for the argument type(s) double, ArrayList"

I feel like im close to having this right, but who knows. i could be a mile off.

Comment: Have you tried making sense of the error message? It tells you that it makes no sense to use the operator `*` with a double and an ArrayList. What would a multiplication of a double number and a list give? What do you really want to multiply? What do you conclude? Error messages give you a lot of good informationand hints about what is wrong. Don't ignore them. Also You should use java.util.Random.nextInt(int n).

Comment: What are you trying to do? Is it getting a random item in the list because I think you are looking for something like random in range

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`int num = (int) (Math.random() * myFilms.size());`

`myFilms` is not a number instance, it's an `ArrayList`, so you can't just multiply a `double` to an `ArrayList`.
And I think what you want to do is multiply the size of myFilms, so use `myFilms.size()`.

Comment: thank you very much, this helped alot.. i wont make this mistake again

Answer (score 1):

That simply doesn't work.

You use Random to acquire a whole number (which ideally is between 0 and myfilms.size(); and then you simply do a `myfilms.get(thatIndex);` to acquire that randomly selected movie **from** your list.

In other words: your code uses the multiplication operator "*" on the myfilms object. Which doesn't make any sense; and gives you that message that * is not defined for

```
double [ left hand side --- Math.random() ]
```

and

```
ArrayList [ right hand side --- myfilms ]
```

Instead, you compute that index for example via Math.random * myfilms.size();

Or you just directly use [Random.nextInt(int)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt(int))